# How to store a video/image file from a server in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I want to send a video/image from one iPhone to another iPhone via a Server.
I have successfully sent the file to the server using HTTP POST. But the problem is I want to receive the file from the server and store it in that device as data for further use.

Can any one suggest me a sample code to do the same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use Post to post data to server successfully. Right? Now you can make an API for downloading image/video. When you finish getting data, put it in document folder of your app.
About API, for simplest, just create a link to that file, then use NSURLConnection to download.

Create a URL connection to download:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strFileUrl]]; //strFileURL is url of your video/image
NSURLConnection *conection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO] autorelease];
[conec start];
[request release];
```

Get path of file to save data:

```
strFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName];
```

Your class must adopt 3 methods of NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol: (please read about Protocol and Delegate)

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // create 
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:strFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:strFilePath] retain];// read more about file handle
    if (file)   {
        [file seekToEndOfFile];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)receivedata
{    
    //write each data received
    if( receivedata != nil){
        if (file)  { 
            [file seekToEndOfFile];
        } 
        [file writeData:receivedata]; 
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {
    //close file after finish getting data;
    [file closeFile];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //do something when downloading failed
}
```

If you want to review you file, use a UIWebview to load it:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strFilePath];
[wvReview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL]];
```

Comment: Quang Hà:Can you pos a sample code for this.As I am new in iPhone ,I am not much familiar with these stuffs :)

Comment: Quang Hà:Thank you very much.This is what i am exactly looking for

Answer (score 2):

you can use **WiFi network** to do the file transfer

Use **Bonjour** to do it. you can start from [**here**](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/)

Also please see the Apple.Developer sample [**WiTap**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html)

The WiTap sample application demonstrates how to achieve network communication between applications. Using Bonjour, the application both advertises itself on the local network and displays a list of other instances of this application on the network.

Implement the connection establishment and write your own structure's to transfer you data as small chunk sizes (1024 is better)

Comment: Ramshad:Thanks. Then how can I store the video file as data

Comment: using bundle Videos or PhotoGallery videos ?