# How to create a P2P chat app for iPhone without using a server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, chat

Can anyone tell me, is it possible to create an iPhone chat app without using a server. I just need only two connections.

Comment: see my answer (Witap application) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066719/how-to-store-a-video-image-file-from-a-server-in-iphone/12066798#12066798

Comment: I'm trying to implement the chat app using sockets.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be possible by the two devices have to be directly connected (i.e. bluetooth, wifi, etc.). They may therefore discover each other (at an application layers i.e periodically broadcasted UDP packets on a give port?), create a tcp connection (or UDP but in this case you should ensure at application level all the sent messages are actually received..) on the top of which the actual chat protocol can be realized

Comment: Thanks Silli, is there any other possibility with out direct connection.

Comment: If they were not directly connected they would be indirectly connected which means through a server. The third hypothesis is that they are neither directly nor indirectly connected... in this case they couldn't actually communicate :)