# About ios download/upload files from server

Tags: ios, upload, download

I am a absolutely newbie on the iOS programming. But now I'm implementing an iOS app, which can show the personal file list from the server, of course, you also can download/upload files. 
Now, I only know how to send the request to the server and get the response from it. The server would send me back through JSON. After parser JSON data from the server, my question here is how can I display the file list on my iphone? Transfer JSON to NSDictionary/NSArray, use the UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully parse the JSON data from the server, it should be in NSArray or NSDictionary format. You can try to show it with the code below:

```
NSLog(@"Array/Dictionary: %@", your_parsed_json_data);
```

If you already reach here, the following should be easier for you. You can just show your data in UITableViewController.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.your_array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.your_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

UPDATE for your comment:

Try have a look how to get the entire file directory list by php from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

then, get the array list and send it back to your iPhone via `JSON`. And show them with your `UITableView`.

For how to download file from a server, try checkout this:
[How to store a video/image file from a server in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066719/how-to-store-a-video-image-file-from-a-server-in-iphone)

Comment: Thanks,Chris.But i need more help!! I want my app

Comment: Thanks,Chris.But i need more help!! I want my app display the  server directory,which it looks like the dropbox. eg.I press one folder called my music,i can jump into it,and the app would show me all my songs in the folder my music.How can I get the data from the server to achieve it ?